# URL with query string and hastag navigation

Tags: php, navigation, query-string, hashtag

I have a link `?view=foo`. If selected, a div `id="view"` gets added into which a file is included. div gets closed and a link `#view` is added to jump back to the beginning of the included file. All fine. Thing is, the `#view` link doesn't do anything. Is this because the div is dynamic? Doesn't seem to make any difference if I add the div as part of the static mark-up though. URL rewriting? Split, Explode? What -- if any -- would be the best approach to make the `#view` link work? Sample code below.

```
if (isset ($_GET['view']) && ($_GET['view'] != '')) {
    $view = $_GET['view'];
    echo '<div id="view">';
    include ($view);
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<a href="#view">Top</a>';
}
```

EDIT: Fixed by adding hastag just above dynamic stuff. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I fail to see how that is related -- other then the query string. The issue in the mentioned post is about getting the full URL... whereas I'm asking about in-page (#hash) navigation while the URL contains a query string. Hmm...

Comment: You don't need to modify your title to say "Solved".  Also you can delete your own answer if you think it is no longer useful to anyone.